# Facebook Graph API stopped sending full results

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm making a simple query to facebook Graph like this:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{UserId}/feed?limit=1000&since=0&access_token={AccessToken}
```

Where {UserId} and {AccessToken} are, of course, valid values. The AccessToken is retrieved from a facebook login with the following scope:

```
user_status,friends_status,user_activities,friends_activities
```

When the response has `paging` I call it's `next` value until there is no more paging.

So, when I began testing I received a at least three pages of data with the all user's posts, but out of the blue I'm receiving a single page (sometimes two) with all stories like:

```
A and B are now friends
```

or

```
A updated his cover photo.
```

I have also tried with

```
https://graph.facebook.com/{UserId}/posts?limit=1000&since=0&access_token={AccessToken}
```

with the same result.

Also, if I change `{UserId}` by `me` it works as expected.

At first I thought that I may have reached a poll limit, but I don't get any error, just a subset of the results.

Comment: not an expert on this but glad you put this question up, for me the nextPage link does not return any data , just a blank array.

Comment: Ask a question and leave the link here, I'll see if I can help. I'm no expert either ^.^

Comment: mmm... I added the permission `read_stream` and is working... the strange thing is that it didn't need it before. If it works for a couple of days I'll answer the question, otherwise I'll update the question.

Answer (score 0):

From fb dev page "Querying without the read_stream permission will return only the public view of the data".

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/

Comment: I'm amazed why it was working without that, but it seems you are right. Thanks! I'll check your answer as correct in a couple of days if it hasn't failed again.